# How do I convert this to MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this on a base page class in asp.net 4.

How do I convert or do this on mvc 3?

```
   protected void ForceFullRefreshInFF()
   {
      if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Firefox") 
         Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");//This fails
   }
```

Comment: what does your html helper look like in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may want to store that in your ViewData.  This allows you to use this value across all pages and partials.  I believe "Form" in your case will be targeting the actual FormCollection.

```
protected void ForceFullRefreshInFF()
{
   if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Firefox") 
      ViewData["autocomplete"] = "off";//This fails
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<form autocomplete="<%: ViewData["autocomplete"] %>" ...>
    ...
</form>
```